# getting permission denied when ssh to an instance from ubuntu 23.04 wsl

Tags: 20.04, permissions, ssh, amazon-ec2, 23.04

I recently updated in Ubuntu 23.04 wsl. I use the same certificate for both a very old 2017 aws linux instance and also for new aws linux instance. I am not able to ssh to the old 2017 aws linux instance but am able to ssh to the new  aws linux instance.

I then install Ubuntu 20.04 wsl and in that using the same certificate I am able to ssh to both the new and the old aws instance.
I am also able to ssh from windows command line for both old and new instances.

Do I need to do anything extra so that I can ssh to older instances in Ubuntu 23.04?

Comment: Are you using PuTTY? in that case, you may need to update it, since 22.04 on wards dropped a less secure protocol (I don't remember exactly the details)

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to later versions of openssh not supporting older host key algorithms, such as ssh-dss and ssh-rsa, by default. This can be overridden by using the HostKeyAlgorithms option. Try to connect using something like the following:

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked

```
# vim ~/.ssh/config, add the lines at the beginning
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74258486/584239